# Invalid operands to binary expression：

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef SALESITEM_H
#define SALESITEM_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Sales_data
{
public:
    Sales_data(unsigned num,int pr , string isb):units_sold(num),price(pr),isbn(isb)
{
    cout<<"it works"<<endl;
};
    Sales_data() = default;
    Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data& rhs);

    string Getisbn() ;
    int Getprice() ;
    unsigned Getunits_sold();


private:
    unsigned units_sold;
    int price;
    string isbn;
};
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data& rhs)
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
    price += rhs.price;
    return *this;
}
string Sales_data::Getisbn()
{
    return isbn;
}
int Sales_data::Getprice()
{
    return units_sold;
}
unsigned Sales_data::Getunits_sold()
{
    return units_sold;
}
istream& read(istream& in,Sales_data &book)
{
    in >>book.Getisbn();
    return in;
}
```

And it indicates that issue in Logs

> in>>book.Getunits_sold() 
>   /Users/apple/Desktop/shirley/shirley/Sales_item.h:185:8: Invalid
>   operands to binary expression ('istream' (aka 'basic_istream')
>   and 'string' (aka 'basic_string,
>   allocator >'))

Comment: Post a complete example so we can see your includes. I'm gonna guess `#include <string>` isn't one of them.

Comment: #include<string> is in the header

Comment: Well, there's one `>>` in your example and it doesn't have a string on the right side. There also aren't 185 lines in your example, so I'm going to say they error is in code you're not showing.  Not really sure what you think `in >>book.Getunits_sold();` might do either.

Comment: Sorry to make a mistake.I just edit it to correct. the book.Getisbn() should return a string, but it also shows a syntax error

Comment: First I just wanna use book.isbn, but it is a private member, so I just utilize a const function to return the isbn.

Comment: I believe if you read further down the error logs, you will see something like `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type std::string to an rvalue of type std::string`. Read the _full_ error, work through it, and search for it, until then, research haven't remotely been done.

Comment: Thank you！I have figured out the solution and the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it says that there's an invalid operator to binary expression (float and float). Thank you very much!

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float a;
    float b;

    b = a - (int) a;

    printf("Write a number:");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    if ((b == 0)&&(b % 2 == 0)) {
        printf("It is an integer even number");
    } else if ((b == 0)&&(b % 2 != 0)) {
        printf("It is an integer odd number");
    } else {
        printf("It is a real number");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```